# Angular 14: Form control different default value

Tags: angular, forms, types

I would like to use Angular 14 typed forms. Consider a modell which only accepts numbers for a certain property.
`interface MyFav { foodId: number; }`

Based on this modell I created a FormGroup.
`FormControl<number>(0, nonNullable: true)`

But if I would like to make a `<select>` I cannot set the default value to null due to the type restrictions, but I would NOT select a default value programatically. The user must make a decision.

I wouldnt like to change the modell itself, the `foodId` is not nullable. If I create the FormControl differently (nullable) I have to make sure later its not null.

Comment: What if you try setting the default value to `-1` a negative number?

Comment: You mean set `-1` and a non negative validator? If I just `-1` it will pass required validator and the form will be valid, even if the `select` doesn't show selected option, since there is no food with id `-1`.